# dropdown cannot show over a div with hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

In my case, dropdown cannot show over the card cause the overflow is hidden, any solution ? Pls find bellow the css and html and js for the hover effect of a section. the idea of this card is a card with some text details and a dropdown list and in the right a banner with hover effect to have some options, as on the phone when we swipe to the left to get delete or ...

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var windowsize = $window.width();
  if (windowsize > 767) {
    $('.section2').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    );
  }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
$('.section2').bind('swiperight', function() {
  $('.section2').removeClass('hover');
});
$('.section2').bind('swipeleft', function() {
  $('.section2').removeClass('hover');
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease .4s;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.section1 {
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.section2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition: all ease .4s;
  transform: translateX(90%);
  background-color: purple;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.section2.hover {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.section2 a {
  color: var(--white);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all ease .4s;
}

.section2 a:hover {
  color: var(--gray2);
  background-color: var(--gray1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="section1">
    <div>Ipsus lupem ipsus lupem</div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>Mouse over me</span>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    <a href="">option1</a>
    <a href="">option2</a>
    <a href="">option3</a>
    <a href="">option4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't set card's overflow to visible, then you have to place the drop-down to the parent of the card, and position it absolutely to look like it is placed in the card.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ deals with a similar topic.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please pick the answer that helped you solve your problem. If no, please comment accordingly and explain what is missing.

Comment: no not yes pls see my comment above thanks

Comment: Your question literally was *In my case, dropdown cannot show over the card cause the overflow is hidden, any solution ?* I've answered that question. It is not clear how the other element is related to your question. Please only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `position: relative` from the ancestors. The combination of that and `overflow: hidden` is the cause of your problem.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var windowsize = $window.width();
  if (windowsize > 767) {
    $('.section2').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    );
  }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
$('.section2').bind('swiperight', function() {
  $('.section2').removeClass('hover');
});
$('.section2').bind('swipeleft', function() {
  $('.section2').removeClass('hover');
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease .4s;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.section1 {
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>Mouse over me</span>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the dropdown shows over the div but the banner to swipe on right disappear

Comment: Yes, I reduced your code to the problem you presented, which is why I removed that.

Comment: the problem is because both of them are important for me to be on, if you can help with both of them. thanks